# Why can't I establish a connection in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to create connection, but get message: "Network adapter could not establish connection".

[image]

Also I tried to use SID "xe". Java is installed and works.

Comment: Either oracle listener is down or a firewal is blocking connections to port 1521 or the listener is configured to listen on another port than 1521.

Comment: @krokodilko Thanks, I also have problem with Oracle Universal Installer, so can't check it yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120341/how-to-install-universal-oracle-installer-on-ubuntu

Comment: Try with IP as hostname

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tnsping localhost
```

if it cannot establish a success conncettion check

1- Firewall on your local machine and server,

2- `lsnrctl status` (check listener is open. If not; `lsnrctl start`),

Comment: Thanks, but also I can't get tnsping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120341/how-to-install-universal-oracle-installer-on-ubuntu