# How to install Universal Oracle Installer on Ubuntu?

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, installation, universal

I can't run [Oracle Universal Installer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/winsoft-098398.html) to get **tnsping**. 
I downloaded **ouiosp220160.jar**.
This jar cannot be launched using java -jar, so I unpacked it [as described on Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/winsoft-098398.html), but there description for Solaris and Windows, I unpacked it and there is folder for Solaris which contains executable that I can't launch.

Comment: You are trying to install tnsping on an Oracle linux client, not an Oracle linux  RDBMS server? Oracle Software Packager, what you linked to, is software that lets you package your software so that OUI can install it. OSP is not what you need if you want to install tnsping or any other Oracle product.

Comment: @jeff6times7 so I can't get tnsping for  Ubuntu ?

Comment: Of course, tnsping runs on many versions of linux. Therefore, you should be able to get it. But you cannot get it by using OSP. My recommendation to you is to post your question at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). SO is better suited for asking software development questions *after* the tools have been installed.

Answer (score 1):

I used this article when did installation:
[Installing Oracle 11g R2 Express Edition on Ubuntu 64-bit](http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html)

it was some manual changes in settings that we had to make, so just go step-by-step through the page

- one more page
  [HOWTO install Oracle 11g on Ubuntu Linux 12.04](https://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/archives/howto-install-oracle-11g-ubuntu-linux-1204-precise-pangolin-64bits)